# Error when trying to create a new database using MySQL with Mac

Tags: mysql, database

My machine is 10.11 El Capitan. From terminal, I successfully started MySQL program:

```
MURAK223:~ Main$ sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
Password:
Starting MySQL
SUCCESS!
```

And then:

```
MURAK223:~ Main$ create database project1
-bash: /usr/local/bin/create: Permission denied
```

Checked with:

```
MURAK223:~ Main$ show databases
-bash: /usr/local/bin/show: Permission denied

MURAK223:~ Main$ sudo ./mysql -u root -p
sudo: ./mysql: command not found
```

Something messing up with my PATH?

```
MURAK223:~ Main$ $PATH
-bash: /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/Users/Main/anaconda/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/metasploit-framework/bin:/opt/metasploit-framework/bin: No such file or directory
```

Or is it something to do with using my company's wi-fi (it didn't work at my home tho).

Comment: This sounds like you don't have the right permissions to do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is:

```
Permission denied
```

means the user by which you are logged-in and trying to create datatabse does not have right permission. Assign the right permission and try again.